# ZPL how to print the current date and time on the label after peeling off?

Tags: zpl, zpl-ii

How to print the current date and time on the label after peeling off ?

For example:

Print the 1st Label: `2019-10-28 18:58:01`

Wait 5 second and peel off label.

The second label must be `2019-10-28 18:58:06`

Currently I have this:

`^FC%,{,#^FD%Y-%m-%Y%H%M%S^FS`

The date and time are still the same `2019-10-28 18:58:01` on each label.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are printing a batch of labels with ^PQ setting the print quantity.  You need to add the following near the top of your label format, before any ^FO or ^FT commands:

```
^SLT
```

The command changes the RTC mode to "Time Now Mode".